# Handle missing values : When 99% of the data is missing from most columns (important ones)

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I am facing a dilemma with a project of mine. Few of the variables don't have enough data that means almost 99% data observations are missing.

I am thinking of couple of options -

- Impute missing value with mean/knn imputation
- Impute missing value with 0.

I couldn't think of anything in this direction. If someone can help that would be great.

P.S. I am not feeling comfortable using mean imputation when 99% of the data is missing. Does someone have a reasoning for that? kindly let me know.

Data has 397576 Observations out of which below are the missing values
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgJUo.png)

Answer (score 1):

99% of the data is missing!!!???
Well, if your dataset has less than 100,000 examples, then you may want to remove those columns instead of imputing through any methods.
If you have a larger dataset then using mean imputing or knn imputing would be ...OK. These methods don't catch the statistics of your data and can eat up memory. Instead use Bayesian methods of Machine Learning like fitting a Gaussian Process through your data or a Variational Auto-Encoder to those sparse columns. 

1.) Here are a few links to learn and use gaussian processes to samples missing values from the dataset: 
[What is a Random Process](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/ee/ee278/ee278.1152/lect06-2.pdf)? 
[How to handle missing values with GP?](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/de85/50f00947d8dbcb1385b339780597daf05d7f.pdf)

2.) You can also use a VAE to impute the missing values!!!
[Try reading this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03653)

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have 397536 observations. For most data columns, missing observations are around 394500. So that way if I am using any imputation method, I will be imputing 99% of the data with the mean collected from 1% of the data. I will check these links out. thank you for the help Tirth.

Comment: I have also added a summary of missing values in my original question for your reference.

Comment: Most of your data is missing so removing columns is not an option. I would highly recommend using a VAE to impute the missing values. Hese's a implemented VAE - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KcecEglmATu-Y9eQA2ueES1IbnurNqLK

Answer (score 0):

My first question to give a good answer would be:

> What you are actually trying to archive with the completed data?

.
People impute data for different reasons and the use case makes a big difference for example you could use imputation as:

1. Preprocessing step for training a machine learning model
2. Solution to have a nice Graphic/Plot that does not have gaps
3. Statistical inference tool to evaluate scientific or medical studies

99% of missing data is a lot - in most cases you can expect, that nothing meaningful will come out of this.

For some variables it still might make sense and produce at least something meaningful - but you have to handle this with care and think a lot about your solution.

In general you can say, imputation does not create entries out of thin air. A pattern must be present in the existing data - which then is applied to the missing data.
You probably will have to decide on a variable basis what makes sense.

Take your variable email as an example:
Depending how your data - it might be that each row represents a different customer that has a specific email address. So that every row is supposed to be a unique mail address. In this case imputation won't have any benefits - how should the algorithm guess the email. But if the data is structured differently and customers appear in multiple rows - then an algorithm can still fill in some meaningful data. Seeing that Customer number 4 always has the same mail address and filling it for rows where only customer number 4 is given and the mail is missing.